# Two models in one Winbugs script

Tags: r, winbugs

I am conducting a Bayesian analysis using Winbugs from R. I need to combine two Winbugs scripts into one: however, I am receiving an error message (`Variable x2 is not defined in model or in data set`). Here is the winbugs code:

```
model{
# Model’s likelihood
 for (i in 1:n) {
    tto[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i], tau ) # stochastic componenent
    b[i] ~ dnorm(0.0, tau2)
    # link and linear predictor
    mu[i] <- 1 - (beta.concern2*concern2[i] + beta.concern3*concern3[i] + b[i])
 }

 for (i in 1:1002) {
    # Linear regression on logit
    logit(p[i]) <- beta.concern2*x2[i,1] + beta.concern2*x2[i,2]

    # Likelihood function for each data point
    y2[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
 }

  s2<-1/tau
  s <-sqrt(s2)

  a2<-1/tau2
  a <-sqrt(a2)

  }
```

where `x2` is a 1002*2 matrix and `y` is a vector

This is the R code definining the data:

```
 combined.data <- list(n=n,tto=tto,concern2=concern2,
                       concern3=concern3,y2=y2, x2=x2)
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please notice that a good practice before asking questions is doing some research. You might want to edit your question, to show what have you tried. This will help you to get more and better answers, besides avoiding to be downvoted.

Comment: @Giulio, I think this question is absolutely legitimate as it is asked. In the majority of WinBUGS errors, there's no research you can do. Just attempt and failure. Why would not he shorten his torture and ask for help? That's what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: @Tomas, I'm not experienced about WinBUGS specifically, but I'm sure you can try modifying some portions of code to solve the bug.

Comment: @Tomas, thank you very much. You get me very well. I really did my best, winbugs is not very friendly towards new users.

Comment: can you dump the resultant combined.data here? Especially the `n` constant. It is important if the x2 is full of numbers (no NA), and the correct dimensions.

Comment: @Guilio, of course - this is valid for any bug - just modify your code and correct it, that's all :-) Stackoverflow is fine, but I think the hospitality of more experienced people towards others could be improved.

Comment: @James, yes, actually! WinBUGS can be a nightmare. I would advice you to try jags. And run it from R with R2jags.

Comment: @James: there isn't *that* much difference between JAGS and WinBUGS, although JAGS's error messages are admittedly slightly clearer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 about constructing a *reproducible example* ... you haven't showed us (1) what your data are, (2) how you passed `combined.data` to the WinBUGS model ... (e.g. are you using `R2WinBUGS` ? What was the precise `bugs()` function call?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be making quite a few assumptions here...

Perhaps you could add a diagram illustrating the relationships between the variables, and which are deterministic vs stochastic. I find this helpful when making models in BUGS. Also, it would be helpful to have the dimensions of all your data, the meaning of `n` and perhaps some context or detail on what you're modelling and the nodes in which you're interested.

I'm guessing that `y` is a binary (0,1) vector of length 1002, and has corresponding values for `x2[,1]` and `x2[,2]` (herein `x1`, `x2`) and `concern2`, `concern3` (herein `c2`, `c3`) and `tto` i.e.

```
nrow(x2) == 1002
```

Here's some sample data with of `nrow==10` to work with:

```
y <- sample(x=c(0,1), size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
x2 <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
c2 <- rnorm(10)
c3 <- rnorm(10)
tto <- rnorm(10)
```

It appears that you're trying to determine the values of `beta.concern2` (herein `b2`) for both values of `x2` in the logit. Not sure why you'd want to fit it with the same parameter for two different predictors. In case this is a typo I'm giving `b2` and `b3` as parameters instead. I hope you'll be able to adapt this to your needs.

The product of these values of `b2`, `b3` (stochastic) and `c2`, `c3` (given) are used to generate a variable `mu`, which also has an error term. (I'm presuming `b[i]` (herein `b1[i]`) is a normally distributed error term.)
Then `tto` is a normally distributed variable which depends on the value of `mu`, and itself has an error term. I have set the precision of the error terms as being equal in both cases.

So for such a model:

```
require(rjags)

### The data
dataList <- list(
    x1 = x2[,1],
    x2 = x2[,2],
    y = y,
    c2 = c2,
    c3 = c3,
    tto = tto,
    nRowX = nrow(x2)
    )

### make sure logistic model can be fitted
f1 <- stats::glm(dataList$y ~ dataList$x1 + dataList$x2 -1, family=binomial(logit))
show(f1)

### set some approximate initial values
b1Init <- 0.1 # arbitrary
b2Init <- f1$coef[2]
b3Init <- f1$coef[3]

initsList <-  list(
 b1 = b1Init,
 b2 = b2Init,
 b3 = b3Init)

### Model: varying parameters (b2, b3) per observation; 2x error terms
modelstring <- "
    model {
        for(i in 1:nRowX){
            tto[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec)
            mu[i] <- 1 - (b1 + b2*c2[i] + b3*c3[i])
            y[i] ~ dbern(L[i]) # L for logit
            L[i] <- 1/(1+exp(- ( b2*x1[i] + b3*x2[i]) ))
        }
        b1 ~ dnorm(0, prec) # precision
        prec <- 1/sqrt(SD) # convert to Std Deviation
        SD <- 0.5
        b2 ~ dnorm(0, 1.4) # arbitrary
        b3 ~ dnorm(0, 1.4)
    }
"

writeLines(modelstring,con="model.txt")

parameters <- c("b1","b2","b3") # to monitor
adaptSteps <- 1e4 # "tune in" samplers
burnInSteps <- 2e4 # "burn in" samplers
nChains <- 3
numSavedSteps <-2e3
thinSteps <- 1 # Steps to "thin" (1=keep every step).
nPerChain <- ceiling(( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains) # Steps per chain

rm(jagsModel) # in case already present

jagsModel <- rjags::jags.model(
 "model.txt", data=dataList,
 inits=initsList, n.chains=nChains,
 n.adapt=adaptSteps)

stats::update(jagsModel, n.iter=burnInSteps)

### MCMC chain
MCMC1 <- as.matrix(rjags::coda.samples(
 jagsModel, variable.names=parameters,
 n.iter=nPerChain, thin=thinSteps))

### Extract chain values
b2Sample <- as.vector(MCMC1[,grep("b2",colnames(MCMC1))])
```